# Error while stacking multiple outputs in one table

Tags: tables, stack, stata

I'm trying to generate 3 panels of regression outputs, as shown in https://medium.com/@linglp/nice-regression-tables-in-stata-17d3895befd2, after running the regressions in stata. I implement the code exactly as shown in the above link. However, while compiling I get error that

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.83 \begin{table}[htbp]\centering \\
                                      \def\sym#1{\ifmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\...

?
```

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering \\ \def\sym#1{\ifmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} \\ \caption{title} \\ \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}} \hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{y1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{y2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{y3}\\
\hline \\ \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}} \\\\[-1ex]
1.treatment&       0.122\sym{***}&      -0.216\sym{***}&       1.406\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.006)         &     (0.007)         &     (0.046)         \\
[1em]
1.after&      -0.005         &       0.033\sym{**} &       0.406\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.009)         &     (0.012)         &     (0.063)         \\
[1em]
1.treatment\#1.after&       0.055\sym{***}&      -0.085\sym{***}&      -0.549\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.008)         &     (0.008)         &     (0.057)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &       0.105\sym{***}&       0.492\sym{***}&       5.769\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.008)         &     (0.010)         &     (0.061)         \\
\hline
R-squared   &       0.198         &       0.108         &       0.095         \\
No. of observations&     1.4e+05         &     1.4e+05         &     6.8e+04         \\
fixed effect1&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
fixed effect2&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
Control variables&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\hline \\ \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Panel B}} \\\\[-1ex]
1.treatment2&       0.170\sym{***}&      -0.103\sym{***}&       1.064\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.021)         &     (0.021)         &     (0.113)         \\
[1em]
1.after&       0.012         &       0.056\sym{*}  &       0.305\sym{*}  \\
            &     (0.017)         &     (0.023)         &     (0.150)         \\
[1em]
1.treatment2\#1.after&       0.074\sym{***}&      -0.123\sym{***}&      -0.253\sym{**} \\
            &     (0.012)         &     (0.013)         &     (0.091)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &       0.034\sym{*}  &       0.316\sym{***}&       6.599\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.017)         &     (0.022)         &     (0.143)         \\
\hline
R-squared   &       0.212         &       0.128         &       0.128         \\
No. of observations&     2.5e+04         &     2.5e+04         &     1.3e+04         \\
fixed effect1&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
fixed effect2&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
Control variables&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\hline \\ \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Panel C}} \\\\[-1ex]
1.treatment3&       0.170\sym{***}&      -0.103\sym{***}&       1.064\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.021)         &     (0.021)         &     (0.113)         \\
[1em]
1.after&       0.012         &       0.056\sym{*}  &       0.305\sym{*}  \\
            &     (0.017)         &     (0.023)         &     (0.150)         \\
[1em]
1.treatment3\#1.after&       0.074\sym{***}&      -0.123\sym{***}&      -0.253\sym{**} \\
            &     (0.012)         &     (0.013)         &     (0.091)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &       0.034\sym{*}  &       0.316\sym{***}&       6.599\sym{***}\\
            &     (0.017)         &     (0.022)         &     (0.143)         \\
\hline
R-squared   &       0.212         &       0.128         &       0.128         \\
No. of observations&     2.5e+04         &     2.5e+04         &     1.3e+04         \\
fixed effect1&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
fixed effect2&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
Control variables&         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\hline\hline \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\\multicolumn{2}{l}{footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***}\(p<0.001\)}\\ \end{tabular}\\ \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreicated, thanks!

Comment: `\\ ` immediate after `\centering` (or after another `\\ ` in contexts like `\centering`) is not allowed. `\\ ` at the very beginning of a `table` environment does not make sense and is always a mistake. Remove all the `\\ ` outside the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @cabohah removed all \\ outside tabular environment. now i'm getting new error:

```! Undefined control sequence.
\sym #1->\ifmode 
                 ^{#1}\else \(^{#1}\)\fi 
l.87 1.treatment&       0.122\sym{***}
                                      &      -0.216\sym{***}&       1.406\sy...

? 
```

Comment: This is another question. And as the error message says: `\ifmode` is not a valid command. For example `\ifmmode` would be one. But why do you use such broken code???

Comment: @cabohah I'm using the code from the blog https://medium.com/@linglp/nice-regression-tables-in-stata-17d3895befd2

I changed to ```\ifmmode``` but now it generates some new error ```! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 
                        
l.140 ...tnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}
                                                  \\\multicolumn{2}{l}{footn...

? ```

Every correction in one place seems to generate new error and I'm not able to figure out how to work this problem. Would appreciate any help

Comment: The code there already uses `\ifmmode`. So this was your own typo. But `\\ ` mistakes are there too. So I would not recommend to use code from this blog or only with caution. Unfortunately, the fact that someone publishes code on the WWW does not necessarily mean that this code is recommendable. Unfortunately there is a lot of ugly and faulty LaTeX code in the WWW. Similarly, code that may be quite useful for a particular case may be better not used in general. So please be careful with LaTeX code from sources of unknown quality of LaTeX know-how.